# Cordova Status bar plugin iOS 9

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, cordova

I hope you can help me, I´m working with Cordova, but I have an issue, when I start the app, the status bar sow an extra space, I have configured the xml config file like this:

```
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default" />
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
```

[image]

The HTML is for this page is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="background-color: #28BCEB;" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
  <title>Parallax Template - Materialize</title>

  <!-- CSS  -->
  <!--<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">-->

  <link href="css/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
  <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%;">
  <!--  Contenidos   -->


  </div>

  <!-- Modal Structure -->


  <!--  Scripts-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

At this moment I´ve to modified the plugin, the file CDVStatusBar.m -> method -(void)resizeWebView, I have to substract 10 to the status bar frame, to prevent the extra space in the status bar.

```
if (!self.statusBarOverlaysWebView) {
            CGRect statusBarFrame = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame;
            statusBarFrame = [self invertFrameIfNeeded:statusBarFrame];
            CGRect frame = self.webView.frame;
            frame.origin.y = statusBarFrame.size.height -10;
            frame.size.height -= statusBarFrame.size.height;
            self.webView.frame = frame;
        }
```

Comment: I guess its more to do with your code than the configuration. Could you post your html code?

Comment: I´ve updated the question

Comment: Possibly something in your CSS is accounting for the status bar, so using the plugin creates essentially a double height status bar vertical gap.

Comment: @JorgeMejia I agree with Simon. Potential CSS issue i feel.

Comment: I´ve reviewed my css I only have body margin 0 and htm-body height 100% I don´t know if this affect the status bar